# How to execute a few task after from few hour to dozens of days in iOS?

Tags: ios

Even if I slide the application to kill the process, I want to run the task after a few hours to several tens of days.

Task is to get location information every few seconds.

Comment: Please be precise, what is sliding, what is a task ?

Comment: sliding is press home button two times and slide up application.
task is to get location information every few seconds.


I want to create a function to collect location information automatically when the specified time comes

Comment: you should look for application lifecycle, your code will probably run in AppDelegate (applicationWillTerminate)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just store the last task `Date` to the `SharedPreference`, every time the app launches, you can compare the current date with it, if the difference is greater than you expected interval (e.g. 30 days), you can run the task again and update the stored `Date` with the current date.